How to set applyImmediately for DB instances when using rds.DatabaseCluster and rds.ClusterInstance.provisioned in AWS CDK
I'm provisioning an RDS database cluster with an instance using the rds.DatabaseCluster and rds.ClusterInstance.provisioned constructs in AWS CDK TypeScript. I need to set the applyImmediately property for the DB instance associated with the cluster.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
const writerInstance = new rds.ClusterInstance.provisioned('WriterInstance', {
    instanceType: props.instanceType,
    instanceIdentifier: props?.instanceIdentifier,
    enablePerformanceInsights: props?.performanceInsightsEnabled,
    parameterGroup: rds.ParameterGroup.fromParameterGroupName(this, 'ParameterGroup', props.dbParameterGroupName)
});

this.rdsCluster = new rds.DatabaseCluster(this, "ProvisionedRdsCluster", {
    engine: props.engine,
    vpc: props.vpc,
    writer: writerInstance,
    clusterIdentifier: props.clusterIdentifier,
    credentials: rds.Credentials.fromPassword(props.masterUsername, props.masterPassword),
});

I want to set the applyImmediately property on the DB instance. How can I do this when using ClusterInstance.provisioned inside DatabaseCluster?

What do you mean by applyImmediately property? I don't think DB instances have such a property.

You cannot set the property applyImmediately, as it does not exist in CloudFormation.
Regarding to the CloudFormation documentation, changes to the DatabaseInstance are applied immediately: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-rds-dbinstance.html

PreferredMaintenanceWindow.
This property applies when AWS CloudFormation initially creates the DB instance. If you use AWS CloudFormation to update the DB instance, those updates are applied immediately.

See also this quote from here: https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cloudformation-coverage-roadmap/issues/597#issuecomment-1438357012

As of now, CFN applies all changes immediately: including AWS::RDS::DBInstance and AWS::RDS::DBCluster. Currently, there are no plans to expose this attribute as it would immediately conflict with the drift detector.

